# AEM's .content.xml requirements

Tags: xml, adobe, aem

I've never used AEM and another team is in charge of the deployment, but the workflow that's been put in place seems to be needlessly complex so I wanted to get some confirmation from people who have used it before. We have a very simple website of three pages, written in HTML (along with CSS for formatting and some simple JS to handle button clicks and other events). Everytime we need to deploy it through AEM to make use of their analytics, that HTML has to be converted to XML and put into .content.xml and all the special characters replaced (< becomes & lt;, " becomes & quot; etc), the head and body tags removed so you can split your html into sections and put them in the content.xml into "body=" and "head=".

It's not the end of the world, since if those steps are consistent at least a script can do it, but can AEM actually not handle HTML? That seems ridiculous for something meant to handle web analytics (I can't think of anyone that actually builds websites XML first). I'm sincerely hoping the person deploying just isn't aware of all of the features or something.

Comment: The quick and dirty answer is: AEM is a CMS that can handle many formats including html, json, ...

Comment: Why do you not have a local AEM instance to make the content updates and then manage the deployment via a content package?

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty answer is: AEM is a CMS that can generate many formats including html, json, ...

But you are trying to import html and add stuff to it.

From my point of view, the whole content generation and enrichment process you describe sound like a real hack. Why would you import html in AEM? And no, you do not have to convert it into xml, you can just use REST or java APIs to add content (not html) into the repository.